ENI file generation from Twincat with custom datatypes
I want to generate a ENI file representing my network topology to use in my Embedded project where I have implemented a master ethercat stack.
I have added a master and the slave device to the device tree just like:
TwinCAT Device tree
When I try to export the master configuration, I have noticed that the process image contains some custom types:
ENI process image from twincat
this custom type is a struct containing different elements:
custom struct
I have also noticed that the custom data type definition is not available in the ENI file.
After seaching a litle bit further I have try other tools to generate the ENI file. I have tested with icECAT EtherCAT Configurator and the process image generated is slighty different:
ENI process image from icECAT
As you can see, the individual elements of the struct are exposed in the process image. How can I achieve the same result on Twincat?
As you can see, the individual elements of the struct are exposed in the process image. How can I achieve the same result on Twincat?
